# pinvoke c function - System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, c++, c, pinvoke, dllimport

Im trying to call a C function from C# but im getting a BadImageFormatException.

Here is by C function header:

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) bool validate(char key[]);
}
```

Here is how im calling it from C#

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll")]
static extern bool validate(char[] key);
```

Whats wrong here.

Comment: Try to compile to 64 or 32 bit explicitely.

Comment: Yup that was it. Thanks. Add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling native methods, you should  compile your c# code to 64 or 32 bit explicitely.

```
 project/properties/build/Platform target
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check if 'validate' function is correctly exported from DLL.
You might have not updated the .def file of the DLL project.